# scp to copy file to remote server fails because of permissions

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I think my fundamental problem is that I don't fully understand how ssh / scp works.  But I don't what to google to try to read up on my question.

**Problem Description**

I have created a bash script on serverA.  It tries to scp a file from serverA to serverB. This script will be scheduled as a cron job.

To test whether this script will work, I just tried to manually scp the file from serverA to serverB. 
But I'm getting a "Permission denied" error message on serverA.

I logged into serverA in the first place like this:

```
mycomputer#> ssh root@serverA.mydomain
```

**Questions:**

Is the manual scp test even a good idea?  Because I'm logging in using my key into serverA but ultimately, it's the cron job that's going to trigger to scp command.

How do I know under what user ID / keys the cron job will attempt the copy?

What should I google to better understand how this all works?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create the `cron` job?  Did you put it in `/etc/cron.daily` or did you use `crontab -e`?  Also, where is the `permission denied` coming from?  Is it trying to execute the script, or is it logging in to the server, or is it trying to write a file on the remote system?

Comment: @EricRenouf cron is configured to look in a folder called /etc/periodic/daily.  so i just created a script there.  however, its failing when I manually try to scp or ssh from server A to server B.

Comment: It's likely running as `root` then, which I'm guessing is not what you want.

Comment: @EricRenouf how do i check what it's running as, and also properly test to make sure the cron job will work?

Comment: Well, you could create a script along side that just logs the user who's running it (by, say, printing `$USER` to a file).  To get it to run as the right user, you should look at using `crontab` as the desired user to schedule the script, or I suppose if you wanted to in the script running as `root` you could have it use `su` to run the command as the desired user, but that feels less good

Comment: Oh, and looking at your example, I see you're logging in as `root`, so perhaps that's the user you want to do it anyway and we can disregard much of that earlier discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automate something like this you will need to setup public / private keys on either side and then configure ssh for authorized keys in the direction you want to copy. Assuming you are using OpenSSh do the following on both systems:
ssh-keygen -t dsa
cd ~/.ssh
cp id_dsa identity
cp id_dsa.pub authorized_keys
cp id_dsa.pub systemname_id_dsa.pub

Now you will need to copy the last file from the source system to the target system's ~/.ssh directory and then run the following command:
cat systemname_id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys

You should now be able to ssh / scp from source to target without a password for this user. I would suggest not doing this as root, but as another user as it opens up possible security issues when done as root.

Answer (score 1):

for better understanding, I would recommend you to look into these two components from OpenSSH suite (you can do it by `man ssh-keygen` and/or `man ssh-copy-id`):

- `SSH-KEYGEN(1)` — authentication key generation, management and conversion
- `SSH-COPY-ID(1)` — use locally available keys to authorise logins on a remote machine

example (how to make key pair *and* copy it over to remote host):

`SSH-KEYGEN(1)`:

```
$ ssh-keygen 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/X/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/X/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /X/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /X/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
e0:cd:fd:18:45:66:0d:11:a0:08:75:6a:f3:1a:6c:45 X@Z
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|    ... E ..B=   |
|     . = . +  .  |
|      * o   .    |
|     + B . .     |
|      = S o      |
|     . o   +     |
|      .   . .    |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
$
```

&

`SSH-COPY-ID(1)`:

```
$ ssh-copy-id root@Y
The authenticity of host 'Y (Z.Z.Z.Z)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 5e:8e:ad:71:77:6a:c4:16:e6:0e:34:f8:92:b2:ce:9f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@Y's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'root@Y'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

$
```

You then will be able to use `scp` to copy without password prompt...

> Is the manual scp test even a good idea? Because I'm logging in using
>   my key into serverA but ultimately, it's the cron job that's going to
>   trigger to scp command.

before scheduling to cron, I'd do manual test as this way you know what to expect without waiting for scheduled time.

> How do I know under what user ID / keys the cron job will attempt the
>   copy?

`crond` usually runs under root, but to verify you can use following:

```
# ps aux | grep crond | grep -v grep
root      2696  0.0  0.0 126336  1712 ?        Ss   May13   0:01 /usr/sbin/crond -n
#
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy from Server A to Server B using scp you need to:

1) Pick a user on Server B (userB) who should "receive" the files. This user will require write permissions in the directory that files will be copied into.

2) Create a public/private key pair for that user.

3) Place the public key at /.ssh/allowedkeys on Server B.

4) Pick a user on Server A who will send the files. This user will require read permissions on the files to be sent.

5) Place the private key at /.ssh/userB on Server A

6) Write a script to copy the desired files. The copy will be something like
scp -i ~/.ssh/userB somefiles userB@ServerB.example.com:/somedirectory/

7) Log on to Server A as userA and run crontab -e to edit userA's crontab add the script to the crontab with desired settings.

That should get you there.